# Hide, remove or disable the Add to Cart button in WooCommerce, if the product price is zero or 100% Discount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need a solution to hide the "Add to Cart" button from the product page when the product price is zero or 100% Discount

I think the following code is probably for the add to cart section
This code was in the following path
mytheme / woocommerce / single-product / add-to-cart / simple.php

```html
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

if ( ! $product->is_purchasable() ) {
    return;
}

echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );

$prefix = '_studiare_';

$woo_studiare_btn_link = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), $prefix . 'woo_course_url', true);
$woo_studiare_btn_label = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), $prefix . 'woo_course_label', true);?>

<?php if ( ( empty( $woo_studiare_btn_label ) ) && ( empty( $woo_studiare_btn_link ) ) ) :

    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

        <form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <?php
            /**
             * @since 2.1.0.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' );

            /**
             * @since 3.0.0.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );

            woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 1, $product ),
                'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
                'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
            ) );

            /**
             * @since 3.0.0.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );
            ?>

            <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

            <?php
            /**
             * @since 2.1.0.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' );
            ?>
        </form>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url($woo_studiare_btn_link) ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button single_add_to_cart_button_link button alt"><?php echo esc_attr($woo_studiare_btn_label); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

change this code:

```
if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>
```

to:

```
if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->get_price() > 0 ) : ?>
```

Or add below code in your active theme functions.php and check it.

```
function wpcustom_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){
    if( $product->get_price() == 0 )
        $purchasable = false;
    return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'wpcustom_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```